# ¿Cuando utilizar MyISAM y cuando InnoDB?

Tags: mysql

A la hora de elegir el motor de almacenamiento en MySQL ¿cuando debería utilizar InnoDB y cuando MyISAM y de qué depende la elección? ¿Es alguna superior a otra?

En mi caso tengo 8 tablas, algunas de medio millón de registros, otras pequeñas y todas están relacionadas de algún modo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Las únicas razones para usar MyISAM en versiones de MySQL previas a la 5.5, era que InnoDB no soportaba particionar tablas ni crear índices FULLTEXT.

Esas restricciones ya no existen.

La única razón para usar MyISAM es que es más rápido para leer y ligeramente más rápido para insertar (en masa y midiendo un proceso aislado), pero eso es porque tales operaciones efectúan un bloqueo de tabla.

Si vas a tener múltiples updates, o inserciones concurrentes, por ejemplo, **un bloqueo a nivel de tabla es muy ineficiente**, versus un update sobre una tabla InnoDB que utiliza **bloqueo a nivel de fila**, y por tanto permite operaciones concurrentes.

Súmale a todo eso que InnoDB permite el uso de llaves foráneas que son indispensables para mantener la integridad referencial de un modelo de datos, el soporte para transacciones.

En resumen, usa InnoDB porque

- En la versión MySQL actual soporta todo lo que soporta MyISAM
- Llaves foráneas / Integridad relacional
- Bloqueo a nivel de fila
- Transacciones

Todas esas ventajas superan con creces una merma en velocidad de los select.

Answer (score 10):

La elección depende de diversos factores. En tu caso concreto, al necesitar de un **diseño relacional debes usar InnoDB**.

Un breve resumen:

**MyISAM**

- Bloqueo de tabla
- Aumento del rendimiento si nuestra aplicación realiza un elevado número de consultas “Select”.
- Las tablas pueden llegar a dar problemas en la recuperación de datos.
- Permite hacer búsquedas full-text
- Menor consumo memoria RAM
- Mayor velocidad en general a la hora de recuperar datos.
- Ausencia de características de atomicidad ya que no tiene que hacer comprobaciones de la integridad referencial, ni bloquear las tablas para realizar las operaciones, esto nos lleva como los anteriores puntos a una mayor velocidad.

**InnoDB**

- Bloqueo de registros
- Soporte de transacciones
- Rendimiento
- Concurrencia
- Confiabilidad
- Permite hacer búsquedas full-text (mysql >= 5.6)

Permite tener las características ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation and Durability: Atomicidad, Consistencia, Aislamiento y Durabilidad en español), garantizando la integridad de nuestras tablas.

Integridad de datos, cuando los contenidos se modifican con sentencias INSERT, DELETE o UPDATE, la integridad de los datos almacenados puede perderse de muchas maneras diferentes.

InnoDB se recupera de errores o reinicios no esperados del sistema a partir de sus logs, mientras que MyISAM requiere una exploración, reparación y reconstrucción de índices de los datos de las tablas que aún no habían sido volcadas a disco.

Además es probable que si nuestra aplicación hace un uso elevado de INSERT y UPDATE notemos un aumento de rendimiento con respecto a MyISAM.

**Algunos enlaces de interés:**

- [MyISAM vs InnoDB (Ventajas y diferencias)](http://foro.elhacker.net/bases_de_datos/myisam_vs_innodb_ventajas_y_diferencias-t362611.0.html)
- [MyISAM vs InnoDB](https://www.webreunidos.es/blog/myisam-vs-innodb/)
- [MyISAM vs InnoDB](https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/myisam-vs-innodb/)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta tan detallada. En resumen: **siempre utilizaré InnoDB**.

Comment: InnoDB también soporta FULLTEXT, ya no es necesario compensarlo con sphinx

Answer (score 1):

con MyISAM hoy en día la única diferencia que he visto con respecto a innodb es que puedes hacer consultas en campos de texto (muy largos), poniendo como referencia palabras que contenga el mismo,  por ejemplo puedes guardar un párrafo completo, y decir que te traiga el registro que dentro del párrafo contenga las palabras "cabeza" y los traerá, es decir la forma en la que gestiona campos de tipo texto, por lo demás siempre uso innodb, antes habían ciertas restricciones como te respondieron mas arriba.  Yo usaría MyISAM en una tabla que guarde por ejemplo el prólogo de un libro en uno de sus campos o algo así, y que necesite hacer de ello un parámetro de búsqueda.