# ¿Cómo evito el bloqueo de tablas al realizar un comando mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, cron, innodb, myisam

Tengo el siguiente crontab:

```
10 17 * * 2,4 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -h216.70.69.75 -ucountier -pcommx1 countier > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/respaldo_countier_bd_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S).sql
```

funciona correctamente, pero cuando se está ejecutando la pagina web que usa la misma base de datos parece estar bloqueada, no responde bien hasta que no finaliza el backup, supongo que es porque el comando mysqldump bloquea las tablas hasta que termina de procesarse.
¿Cómo debo modificar el comando en el crontab para que las tablas no se bloqueen?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Mirando el manual, tienes la opción `--lock-tables`:

```
$ -> man -P cat mysqldump | grep -A5 'lock-tables, -l'
       ·   --lock-tables, -l For each dumped database, lock all tables to be dumped before dumping them. The tables are locked with READ LOCAL to permit concurrent inserts in the case of MyISAM tables. For
           transactional tables such as InnoDB, --single-transaction is a much better option than --lock-tables because it does not need to lock the tables at all.

           Because --lock-tables locks tables for each database separately, this option does not guarantee that the tables in the dump file are logically consistent between databases. Tables in different
           databases may be dumped in completely different states.
```

En caso de que estés usando el motor InnoDB, mejor usar `--single-transaction`.

Tienes un poco de información de [cuando usar MyISAM o InnoDB](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55741/cuando-utilizar-myisam-y-cuando-innodb) que pueden ayudarte a entenderlo.

Puedes saber el motor que usan las tablas de tu BD con la consulta `SHOW TABLE STATUS` ya que, entre los datos que devuelve, tendrás `Engine` el cuál es el motor.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `nombreBD`;
```

Manual [SHOW TABLE STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html)

Comment: Que debo usar si tengo tablas con MyISAM y otras son InnoDB?

Comment: De acuerdo a la respuesta aceptada de esta pregunta [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6363/consistent-logical-backup-of-databases-that-use-myisam-and-innodb-engineshttps://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6363/consistent-logical-backup-of-databases-that-use-myisam-and-innodb-engines] (créditos al autor). Puedes usar `--single-transaction` de forma correcta y segura si todas las tablas son InnoDB. En caso de que tengas tablas que usen tanto uno como otro mejor utiliza `--lock-tables`.